# Store data associated with a foreign Key in a Django Model

Tags: python, mysql, django, model, foreign-keys

I wanna store data in a Django Table as if I am storing data into some category and item access them in FIFO manner. 
Here I should be able to store a data item to a category.

```
Category:
ID: 1,
Name: firstname
Percentage: 40
```

I have to store them in a different category pass if > 40 and in fail if <40.

```
Table Fail:
ID 1 --> Inserted first
ID 2 --> Insrted second
ID 3 --> Inserted third

Table Pass:
ID 4 --> Inserted first
ID 5 --> Insrted second
ID 6 --> Inserted third
```

For some reason, I have to rank them using the First In First Out(FIFO) method. 
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood very well your question as I miss your data models and the real function you want to use for that purpose, but how you are doing it currently in pseudocode is the correct way.

What you insert first, if you did not define a custom *PrimaryKey* field with different structure, it will have autoincremented IDs, as it is the default behavior for tables in **Django**. After the insertion, you just need to query over them and select the desired order with the *[order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)* function.